# Alternative to a static lease/ip reservation

Tags: networking, router, debian, dhcp

I used to have routers which allowed to make ip reservations based on MAC. But my current router doesn't have this option. What is the alternative for that?

Why do I need it?
I have a Debian server for personal needs and I want to setup some port forwardings, ssh etc. So I need to have a static ip on this server. I do not want to create a static configuration on Debian machine, in that case I will need to explicitly show gateway ip address etc.
Probably some scripts exist which may do a network lookup and dynamically search for a gateway/router address when eth0 is up. Could someone advise a good solution?

Comment: you could install a DHCP server on some other box on the network. most distros have reservation features.

Comment: Heck, you can make that Debian server BE the DHCP server, but obviously you don't make it also a DHCP client. So the "static IP" answer below is the right answer. :-)

Comment: I am using a static configuration for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign as static IP to your "server".
you can do so by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto  eth0
## uncomment the line that says DHCP
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
## add static IP-settings
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

this will assign your machine an IP `192.168.0.10`. obviously you should assign your server a valid IP for your subnet (the given configuration assumes that your DHCP-server gives out IP-addresses in the `192.68.0.x` range).

you should also make sure to *not* use an IP that the DHCP-server might give out. usually you can configure it, to e.g. only hand out IPs in a certain range (e.g. `192.168.0.100-250`). mak sure that your static IP is outside this range and does not collide with other devices (namely the router itself - most likely `192.168.0.1`; and the network&broadcast addresses `192.168.0.0` & `192.168.0.255`)

Comment: This. Then you can either just add this IP to other machine's `/etc/hosts` file if you want to be able to ping it and ssh into it by a name instead of just by its dotted ip number.

Answer (score 0):

Your router probably enables you to reserve a range of unused IPs.  You can then set this range in a DHCP server, or even statically if your configuration is simple enough.

An alternative is if your router enables you to set very long lease times.